# Cannot access function within model in ZEND

Tags: php, class, zend-framework, model

Can anyone see why my check_multi function would return a --

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function check_multi() in
>   /var/www/vhosts/aero.onelinksoftware.com/application/models/Design.php
>   on line 21

The above error shows up and I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I tried setting my function as public, private, static, and other combinations but no matter what I try; the system still errors out. Can you not call a function inside a Model in Zend? I don't understand why I cannot use a function I created if it is inside a class I made.

If I echo and die before the check_multi call; I can see my text and such. I have also performed a php test for syntax and it is valid as far as it reports.

```
class Model_Design
{
    /**
     * Constructs our partials.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($key)
    {
        // Get the DB Connection
        $db = Zend_Registry::Get('db');
        // Setup the SQL Statement
        $sql = $db->select()->from('design', array('id'));
            // Get the Result
            $result  = $sql->query();
            // Get our Row
            $row     = $result->fetchAll();

            if(check_multi($key, $row)) {
                echo "omg"; die();
            }

        // Make sure the id isn't empty
        if (empty($key)) {
            throw new Exception('You have a disturbing lack of variables.');
        }

        // Store the id
        $this->variables = $key;


        // Construct our query
        $sql = $db->select()->from('design')->where('`id` = ?', $key);
            // Get the result
            //$result    = $sql->query();
            //$row   = $result->fetch();
    }

    private function check_multi($n, $arr)
    {
        foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
            if ($n===$key) {
                return $key;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$this->check_multi($key, $row);
```

To access a variable or function from inside its container class you must use $this. $this is the current instance of the class.

Answer (score 1):

How do you call the function ? use `$this->check_multi($n,$arr);` or you can try [function_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php) to check if function really exist

Comment: This is the answer as well; upvoting since it is correct but Iznogood answered first.

Comment: I'm new to Stack overflow.I was typing the answer while he answered the question

Comment: @NavneetSingh yeah its often like that. Kind of a race :) Welcome to stackoverflow :)